# Не работает on_message в discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Перерыл все существующие вопросы, никак не смог починить

```
import discord # Подключаем библиотеку
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default() 
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
client = discord.Client(intents = discord.Intents.all())


@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    await bot.process_commands(ctx)

    msg = ctx.content.lower()

    if ctx.channel == 982215160716472340:
        await ctx.channel.send(f'Новое предложение - {msg}')
        await bot.process_commands(ctx)
```

Comment: Для начала нужно хотя бы [**запустить**](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/discord-py.md#%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0) бота. А затем определиться, какого боты вы будете использовать (`commands.Bot` или `discord.Client`), потому что вы зачем-то определили в коде сразу обоих, а используете только `bot`.

Comment: да, спасибо, прошу прощения что так поздно